# SVG is sharp and clear but font is blurry even with font smoothing set to none

Tags: css, svg, fonts

Help!

Even though I set -webkit-font-smoothing: none; my font is still blurrier than the SVG it was created from.

I tried setting `-webkit-font-smoothing: none !important;`but it made no difference. I verified I was targeting the right element by also changing `color:red`. However nothing seems to fix the blurriness.

[image: The third right icon is an SVG, the fourth one is a font created with the SVG.]

The third right icon is an SVG, the fourth one is a font created with the SVG.

I am sure this is related to some form of font smoothing, is it perhaps controlled by the browser or windows itself?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The original SVG was not **aligned to pixel grid**, causing blurriness. After aligning the pixels to the grid and recreating the font the problem was solved and font ended up sharp. Hurrah!